# How do I test that the URL has been called in jasmine and check the return value for a promise

Tags: javascript, angular, jasmine

I have code like this:

```
  getImageBlob(docLink: string): Promise<Blob> {
    const httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders({
      'TOKEN': token,
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET, HEAD, OPTIONS',
    });
    return this.http.get<Blob>(docLink, { headers: httpHeaders, responseType: 'blob' as 'json' }).toPromise();
  }
```

I want to  test this using Jasmine. I wrote this but not sure if this is actually doing any test:

```
it('should getImageBlob file from API via GET', () => {
    tokenServiceMock.getToken.and.returnValue('xyzToken');
    service.getImageBlob(mockImageLink).catch(err => {
      expect(err.status).toBe(200);});
  });
```

Comment: _"not sure if this is actually doing any test"_ - so break the implementation and see if it fails. It's not clear why you'd expect an error thrown with a 200 OK status though.

Comment: That where I need help. I am not sure how to test the method.

Comment: So read the docs: https://angular.io/guide/testing, https://angular.io/guide/http#testing-http-requests. Your current test suggests you don't actually know what the code is supposed to do, so a starting point might be working that out.